# Xcode 12 builds Document file instead of Unix file when using SDL2 and c++ (command line tool) MacOS 11.2.3

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl, sdl-2, xcode12

Hello I am working on simple game engine with SDL2 and c++ in Xcode 12.4 (command line tool). My Problem is that when I include SDL and run the project, the Product is a Document file instead of a Unix file. Xcode runs the project with no problems but I cant use it. When I tested it without SDL, it compiled to a unix file. I set Xcode to default but that changed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. I may have named my project "Engine 1.1", which means that the compiled file was also called "Engine 1.1". As a result, the file extension ".1" was not recognized. Since the Unix files have no extensions in MacOS, I didn't notice that. So when you create a project in Xcode, just don't use dots.